# 8 person purchased 6 types of beverages, each person purchased one type. In total, how many different ways of buying these beverages?

Tags: combinatorics

8 person purchased 6 types of beverages, each person purchased one type. In total, how many different ways of buying these beverages?

I would say that as each of the 8 eight person has 6 choices, it would be

> 8^6

but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, each person has $6$ choices. And there are $8$ persons. So the answer should be $6^8$. This directly follows from [Rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).